# Determining C code's processor cache efficiency

Tags: c, caching, code-analysis

I'd like to determine how efficiently given C code utilises processor cache, and if possible, determine what data is present in the cache and what is stored in main memory (though that is more of a nice-to-have) - is there software out there that can do this?

I know this may not fit into the remit of stack overflow, though of course it is highly related to programming as I intend to use it as a tool to test code I am writing. If there is a more appropriate place, please let me know/mods move this question.

Additionally, I'd (much) prefer the software to be for mac os x/unix.

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't that efficiency depends upon the processor, as the C compiler doesn't have much control over the cache usage - besides the choice of the instructions?

Comment: @ring0 - absolutely, so I'd expect the software to adapt to the particular processor being tested (and thus of course the results aren't applicable to different processors). In terms of C - it'd be useful to have the ability for the tool to indicate, in terms of C code via generated debugging symbols, what code is a hotspot for cache misses, whether entire data structures are sitting in the cache, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various profilers which can capture profiles based on cache misses as an alternative to regular time interval based sampling. This will give you an idea as to where in your program you are not using cache effectively. On Mac OS X check out [Shark](http://developer.apple.com/tools/sharkoptimize.html) (free - part of the CHUD tools package). On Linux try [Zoom](http://rotateright.com) (commercial, but there's a free 30 day evaluation license).